# lines in projective space with non-algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, grassmannian

I apologize in advance for this possibly trivial question.
Let $k$ be a field that is not necessarily algebraically closed. We consider $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ and let $l$ be a line in it. There is a definition
Definition. A line $l\in\mathbb{P}^3_k$ is a closed point of $Gr(2,4)$ (the set of 2-dimensional subspaces of $k^4$). The residue field of this closed point is called the field of definition of $l$. 
Then there is a claim
For a line $l$ with field of definition $L$, we have an associated closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^3_L$. And the point $l\in Gr(2,4)$ gives a morphism $SpecL\to Gr(2,4)$.
My questions are:

1. How do we make sense of this definition? I know that a closed point in some sense means an "actual" point. In this case, a line is indeed a 2-dimensional subspace.
2. What about its field of definition? I checked wiki but did not gain a clear understanding. I think it is a subfield $L$ of the algebraic closure of $k$ such that the elements in our variety have coordinates in $L$. Moreover, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{A}^n_L$.\
3. How does a line $l$ with field of definition $L$ associates to a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^3_L$? And how does it give a morphism $SpecL\to Gr(2,4)$? Set-theoretically, this morphism should be defined by mapping the point to the 2-dimensional subspace corresponds to $l$. But $l$ has field of definition $L$. Does it still give a 2-dimensional subspace of $k^4$?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $\{ [x:y:z:w],x^2+y^2=0,z-w=0\}$ (coming from the 2-dimensional space $\{ (x,y,z,w)\in \Bbb{C}^4,x+iy=0,z-w=0\}$) should be a line in $\Bbb{P^3(R)}$ with field of definition $\Bbb{C}$.

This is because on the set of 2-dimensional subpaces $\Bbb{C}a+\Bbb{C}b\subset \Bbb{C}^4$ we have the rational function $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{a_2b_3-a_3b_2}{a_1b_3-a_3b_1}$ (it is invariant under $(a,b)\mapsto (ar+bs,at+bu)$)

and when evaluating at $a=(1,i,0,0),b=(0,0,1,-1)$ we get $i$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I am not sure if I understood your comments well. Do you mind telling me which question you are answering please?

Comment: @reuns if possible, would you also explain about the definition of "field of definition"? Thanks!

Comment: I may be answering them all, giving a relevant example of what they are talking about. I didn't construct $Gr(2,4)$, you can think to the field/sheaf of rational functions with real coefficients in $a,b$ that are invariant under $(a,b)\mapsto (ar+bs,at+bu)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Let $ X $ be any scheme of finite type over a field $ k $. Let $ p \in X $ be a closed point. Choose an affine open $ U = \operatorname{Spec} A \subset X $ containing $ p $, then $ p $ is a closed point in $ U $ and hence corresponds to a maximal ideal $ \mathfrak{m} $ of $ A $. Since $ A $ is a finitely generated $ k $-algebra, so is the residue field $ k(\mathfrak{m}) = A/\mathfrak{m} $. By Zariski's lemma/Noether normalization, $ k(\mathfrak{m}) $ is a finite field extension of $ k $. Apply this to $ X = G = Gr(2,4, k) $ (I write the base field here because it's important) which is indeed of finite type - this is how you are defining the field of definition of a closed point. Indeed you should think of closed points as actual points, just that these points may not have 'coordinates' in $ k $.

(2) For any scheme $ X $ and a point $ p $ (not necessarily closed) and with residue field $ k(p) $, there is a canonical morphism $$ \operatorname{Spec} k(p) \rightarrow X $$
(A hint if you do not know this: check this when $ X $ is affine first and reduce the general case to the affine case by showing it is independent of the affine neighborhood you choose)
Anyway, since your closed point has field of definition $ L $, there is a morphism $ \epsilon: \operatorname{Spec} L \rightarrow Gr(2,4, k) $. By the universal property of the Grassmanian, there is a universal rank $ 2 $ quotient $ \mathcal{G} $ on $ G $, $$ \mathcal{O}_G^4 \rightarrow \mathcal{G} \rightarrow 0 $$and pulling it back via $ \epsilon $ gives you a rank $ 2 $ quotient on $ \operatorname{Spec} L $,$$ \mathcal{O}_L^4 \rightarrow \mathcal{V} \rightarrow  0 $$ where $ \mathcal{V} $ now just corresponds to a rank $ 2 $ vector subspace of $ L^4 $. Projectivizing the last morphism shows $$ \mathbb{P} (\mathcal{V}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P} (\mathcal{O}_L^4) = \mathbb{P}^3_L $$ and this is the required line, viewed now as a closed subscheme of projective space over $ L $. This answers 3.

Bottom line: all of this is just a rigorous way of saying that your line may be living in a bigger field than $ k $. This is especially important in number theory. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Most of them is clear to me. However I do not understand few points: 1. Is there a way for us to compute the residue field of a point of Grassmannian? 2. How can a line $l$ with field of definition $L$ (living in $L$) be a point of $Gr(2,4;k)$? The latter one contains just 2-dimensional subspace of $k^4$, if I understand. 3. Do you mind giving some refernces regarding the part "universal property of Grassmannian", "universal rank 2 quotient", and "pullback via $\epsilon$" parts?

Comment: 1. Gr(d,n) locally is affine space of dimension d(n-d), in this case 4. So a point corresponds to a maximal ideal of k[x,y,z,w] and the residue field isn't so easy to compute explicitly, of course.

Comment: 2 is where you're wrong. Like the question and my answer says, closed points of Gr(2,4) correspond to two dimensional subspaces in L^4, L a finite extension of k and not just those of k^4. There are more closed points of a scheme of finite type than just the k-valued points, if k is not algebraically closed.

Comment: For 3, check out the book by Gortz and Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry vol 1.

Comment: By the way, by $\mathcal{O}_L^4\to\mathcal{V}\to 0$, do you mean $\mathcal{O}_L^4(Spec L)=L^4$? Similarly, by $\mathcal{O}_G^4$ do you mean the global section?